# Способ образования слова

Tags: словообразование

Здравствуйте. Возникли трудности с восстановлением словообразовательной цепочки: тихо - ...- потихонечку. Какое слово пропущено? Есть подозрение, что пропущенных слов должно быть два. Поделитесь рассуждениями. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, два. Правда, до "тихо" было ещё тихий.Если от "тихо", то так:

Тихо - тихонько - потихоньку - потихонечку.

Но возможно и так:  Тихо - тихонько - тихонечко - потихонечку.
 и способ тогда меняется: 1-суффиксальный,2-приставочно-суффиксальный.

Comment: Спасибо. У слова "тихонько" суф. -оньк- и -о-?

Comment: да, -о- уже был, -оньк- добавился.

Comment: Т.е -О- остался от "тихо"?

Comment: Именно так

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Ефремовой: тихо - тих-онько, суффикс ОНЬКО, тихо - тих-онечко, суффикс ОНЕЧКО, то есть выделяются суммарные суффиксы, также: тихонько - по-тихоньк-у, тихонечко - по-тихонечк-у.
ОТВЕТ 2. Это «Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц». ПО…У – словообразовательная единица, например: долго – подолгу, финаль О мотивирующих наречий отсутствует.
Получим: тих-онечк-о  -   по – тих – онечк – у.

Comment: Это же словообразовательный словарь, а не морфемный, там не выделяются морфемы в каждом случае. Вы же не примете в " по-тихонечк-у" -тихонечк- за одну морфему?